# Magento 2 module install error "data: current version - none, required version 2.0.0"

Tags: module, magento2, setup-script

I'm getting the following error when I try to install my extension.

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Mymodule_Example data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
```

The database entry in setup_module looks like this:

[image]

This is my module.xml file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Mymodule_Example" setup_version="2.0.0">
</module>
</config>
```

Is there something I'm missing to ensure the data version gets added to the DB? A result of this also means my setup scripts aren't running.

Comment: How do you enable the module?

Comment: CLi: php bin/magento module:disable Mymodule_Example

Answer (score 4):

You already have right solution :)

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory
```

In Magento1 *data_version* field was updated on each application call according to to it's value in *config.xml*.

In Magento2 you should do it manually. This on-demand approach helps to avoid such version checks during each application call.

Answer (score 4):

Go and check "setup_module" table, the data_version is "null".

This is happens because of something wrong while running "bin/magento setup:upgrade"

So you have to fix the error then everything ok.

**Temporary solution:**
Login to Mysql database => then update table **setup_module** of the "**data_version**" column same as "**schema_version**"

Comment: This solution worked perfect.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, you just need to execute following commands on terminal from magento root directory -

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After that set 777 permission to your magento root folder recursively.

You also need to delete setup row, to do that open **setup_module**  table in your database and delete your module entry if exist.

Then run this command to register your module -

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

Your may clear cache if required.

Comment: PLEASE NEVER use 777 permissions - especially for your ENTIRE MAGE ROOT DIRECTORY!!!!  Magento has published the correct permissions - use them!  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-set-two-users

Answer (score 1):

Just update your `setup_module` table with the required version, or delete in case of NULL required.

In your case, just put 2.0.0 on data column.

Answer (score 0):

Create file registration.php in a your extension root directory.
In example: app/code/Namespace/Modulename/registration.php

```
<?php
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
 'Namespace_Modulename',
 __DIR__
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it might be helpful to anyone, aside from the above correct answers: I encountered this issue after manually deleting the module record in `setup_module` and then running `setup:upgrade` manually. It turned out that `setup:upgrade` failed, so a new record in `setup_module` was not created.

In case you're running a script like me that runs `setup:upgrade` in this case, make sure the action was successful, and the module actually appears in `setup_module`.